# How to access MovieClip in the Libary using other class beside Main class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've tried searching the web but can't find the exact process on how to do it. Can't pin point it. Any tips, hints or links will be helpful.

So here's the problem, I have MainClass.as and another class named Menu.as, I have no problem adding a movie clip on the MainClass.as

```
public class MainClass extends Sprite { 
   private var startButton:MovieClip = new StartButton();
   private var menu:Menu = new Menu();

   public function MainScript() {
      startButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startButtonHandler);
      addChild(startButton);
   }

   private function startButtonHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
      menu.init();
   }
```

Here's where I encounter problem, I have a MovieClip having a linkage Avatar on the library

```
public class Menu extends Sprite {

    private var avatar:MovieClip = new Avatar();

    public function init() {
       addChild(avatar)
}
```

I'm getting "Call to a possibly undefined method". I'm thinking because It can't be found, Also tried importing (but not sure how to). Any help will be truly appreciated and sorry if ever there's a duplicate thread.

Comment: Post the entire error message. What method is possibly undefined? On what lien does the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a class file for Avatar? What is your base class for Avatar?
"Undefined method" occurs here because there is no class file created and defined for Avatar. Create a new Avatar class file and this should go away. However post your full code to understand this better